# how to set different auth redirect url for different user group in cakedc plugin cakephp3

Tags: cakephp-3.x, cakedc

Am using cakephp3 and cakedc plugin. I have two user groups , 1 is normal user and other is super user
what i am basically looking for is setting different auth url for different user as both user group have different dashbaord.
I tried to hook `UsersAuthComponent::EVENT_AFTER_LOGIN` .This is my code in `eventListener`

```
$helper = new AppView();
$adminDashBoard = $helper->Url->build([
                    'prefix' => 'admin',
                    'controller' =>'users',
                    'action' => 'dashboard',
                    'plugin' => null
                ]);

        $customerDashBoard = $helper->Url->build([
                    'prefix' => 'customer',
                    'controller' =>'customers',
                    'action' => 'dashboard',
                    'plugin' => null
                ]);

        $result = array();
        if($entity['is_superuser'] == 1)
            $result[] = $adminDashBoard;
        else
            $result[] = $customerDashBoard;

        return $result;
```

I had to create object of AppView as Url builder was not available in `EventLister` . Above code is working fine but the url that i have appended in result object gets appended in current URL and it becomes like

```
domain.com/<user's dashboard url in urlencoded format>
```

but i want it to redirect to user's dashboard url which i had set in `eventListner`
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Instead of using the helper, you should be able to call `\Cake\Routing\Router::url([...])`.

Comment: Yes after posting question i had changed the helper to call url method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think about 2 options:

- Override EVENT_AFTER_LOGIN (more complex)
- Create a dashboard action, and 2 different views 1 of each role. Then in the dashboard action you can do something like

  `if ($role === ROLE_ADMIN) {
      $this->render('dashboard_admin');
  } else {
      $this->render('dashboard_user');
  }`

I think option 2 is simple enough to use it, you can extract the common markup from the views into an element and reuse it in both.

Comment: i am using admin lte theme.. do you have any idea how to change template in it ?

Comment: please start another question, looks like the comment is not related. Also would be nice to set the answer as resolved if it was the way to go for you... thanks

Comment: well yeah it guided me towards the anwer. however my issue is still not fixed.